# Multiple (github) PR checks from single azure pipeline yaml

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Maybe i'm missing something obvious, but...

Can i have several (github) PR checks from a single azure pipelines yaml?

For example, on this screenshot i have CI connected to azure pipelines where build & running tests happen within the same check:

[image: Github PR checks]

Can i somehow separate them so i have 2 checks: *Build* and *running tests* and see them pass|fail separately?

Comment: Wouldn't the build have to pass in order to run the tests?

Comment: @NapoleonIkeJones sure, but test could fail and i’d like to see 2 checks there posted where it says *build succeeded* and *test failed*. also, this is just an example. question is if its possible to have N checks in a single yaml and have their statuses posted separately.

Answer (score 1):

> if its possible to have N checks in a single yaml and have their
>   statuses posted separately

For this issue, the answer is yes, you can achieve this with script approach.

Here is an [issue](https://github.com/drone/drone/issues/1509) about Multiple GitHub checks, in this issue, someone has the same problem as you, and got a solution and the exact config is given in it.

Since the build environment is a shell, for example, you could wrap your lint commands in a shell script that traps the exit code and sends the status to GitHub:

```
#!/bin/sh

npm run lint
EXIT_CODE=$?

if [[ $EXIT_CODE == 0 ]]
then
  export STATUS="success"
else
  export STATUS="failure"
fi

GITHUB_TOKEN=<your api token>

curl "https://api.github.com/repos/$CI_REPO/statuses/$CI_COMMIT?access_token=$GITHUB_TOKEN" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -X POST \
  -d "{\"state\": \"$STATUS\", \"description\": \"eslint\", \"target_url\": \"$CI_BUILD_URL\"}"

exit $EXIT_CODE
```

Comment: thanks for your input! so, if i understand correctly, i could have a few tasks defined like `task1 > task2 > task3` and for each, i could have `task1_report.sh`, `task2_report.sh`, `task3_report.sh` (between each `taskX` step) which would all depend on previous task. does that sound like a plausible setup?

Comment: I am not very sure but I think this may be feasible. You can try it and share your test result here.